# Как правильно прописать правило RewriteRule для такого условия?

Tags: apache, mod_rewrite

Есть ulr вида `site.ru/tovar/semena-ovoschey/semena-arbuza/vostochnyj-ornament`. Как мне правильно прописать правило RewriteRule, чтобы получить `site.ru/semena-ovoschey/semena-arbuza/vostochnyj-ornament`?

Категории отображаются вот так: `site.ru/category/semena-cvetov`. Нужно получить `site.ru/semena-cvetov`, т.е. удалить `category`.

Вот файл .htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^category.*$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^tovar/(.*)$ 
RewriteRule ^tovar/(.*)$ $1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^tovar.*$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^category/(.*)$ 
RewriteRule ^category/(.*)$ $1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Но правила не срабатывают, почему? Как их исправить на правильные?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /

   RewriteRule ^(?:tovar|category)/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301, L]

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

[Проверять здесь](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/)

Comment: @romeo редирект работает, но как-то не совсем правильно. Сайт www.seme4ka.com.ua, слово tovar убирает, но попадаю на страницу 404 ;-((

Comment: @Верните `RewriteBase /` Хотя, его можно опустить добавляя слэш к правилам `... /$1 [R=301, L]`. Я добавил оба варианта. Проверяйте.