# Лучший способ сделать редирект .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod_rewrite

Как правильно сделать 301 редирект в случае:
заходим - http://site.com/shop/cat_name/
переадресовываем - http://site.com/category/cat_name/

**UPD.**
Сейчас htaccess стандартный от вордпресса:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On

   RewriteRule ^shop/(.*)$ /category/$1 [R=301, L]
</IfModule>
```

[Проверять здесь](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/)

#### Update

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteRule ^shop/(.*)$ /category/$1 [R=301, L]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Недавно [отвечал на похожий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/401099#401124)

Comment: при таком решении получаю ошибку 500 от сервера, но htaccess у меня не пусто - обновил вопрос текущим кодом

Comment: @Undefitied Дополнил ответ